# How prevent of attack in Ethereum

Tags: blockchain, security, proof-of-stake, proxy-contracts, iot

I hope you are well. The topic of my thesis is to increase security in blockchain-based IoMT (Internet of Medical Things). I aim to present new ideas to reduce attacks in the blockchain, considering that consensus is PoS (Proof of Stake) in Ethereum. Thank you for your advice on which of the attacks I should work on and how to prevent these attacks?

Answer (score 1):

Some common blockchain attacks include

- Denial of service
- Sybil
- Transaction censorship

See [here more on the topic](https://www.seba.swiss/insights/are-blockchains-safe-how-to-attack-them-and-prevent-attacks/).

Note that as a blockchain user, unless you are building your own public blockchain (which you are not), you do not need to do anything. This is the work for those who develop blockchain themselves. The major blockchains today have been in production for many years, seen a share of their issues and can be considered safe today. Bitcoin and Ethereum have less downtime than most of the critical services like Amazon cloud or financial services.